# How to set up Dynamic memory and temporary buffer?

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, malloc

I have been trying to finish this code but I am stuck at creating a temporary buffer. I never learned this before but somehow I need to use it for my program.

From [this website](http://ctips.pbworks.com/w/page/7277635/TempReturnBuffer) I think the best choice would be

```
char * func1() {
     char *buffer = (char *)malloc(1000);
     buffer[0] = '\0'; // Initialize buffer
     // Do processing to fill buffer
     return buffer;
}
```

The following is my code

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LUNCHES 5
#define ARRAY 2

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    struct Food
    {
        char *name;                                                            /* “name” attribute of food */
        int weight, calories;                                                  /* “weight” and “calories” attributes of food */
    }lunch[LUNCHES] = { [0] = {"apple", 4, 100}, [1] = {"salad", 2, 80} };

    for(x = ARRAY; x < LUNCHES; ++x)
    {
        char *buff = malloc(sizeof(lunch[x].name));

        printf("Please input \"food\", weight, calories: ");
        scanf("%s", buff);
        scanf("%d %d", &lunch[x].weight, &lunch[x].calories);
        printf("The %s weighs %doz. and contains %d calories.\n", lunch[x].name, lunch[x].weight, lunch[x].calories);


    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ok changed that. But now the output is

The NULL weighs and contains . why null?

Corrected

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LUNCHES 5
#define ARRAY 2

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    struct Food
    {
        char *name;                                                            /* “name” attribute of food */
        int weight, calories;                                                  /* “weight” and “calories” attributes of food */
    }lunch[LUNCHES] = { [0] = {"apple", 4, 100}, [1] = {"salad", 2, 80} };

    for(x = ARRAY; x < LUNCHES; x++)
    {
        lunch[x].name = malloc(25 * sizeof(char));

        printf("Please input \"food\", weight, calories: ");
        scanf("%s", lunch[x].name);
        scanf("%d %d", &lunch[x].weight, &lunch[x].calories);
        printf("The %s weighs %doz. and contains %d calories.\n\n", lunch[x].name, lunch[x].weight, lunch[x].calories);

        free(lunch[x].name);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, that's not right, and you seriously need to look at that `for` loop again.

Comment: OK. You need to say `lunch[x].name = malloc(952);`, and then `scanf("%951s", lunch[x].name)`.

Comment: Do I have to allocate memory size? Because I want the program to figure out how much to use.

Comment: And how is the program supposed to do that?

Comment: You're using the buffer for user input. How can you know how much the user will type? You should allocate a reasonable size, and then use this size in your `scanf` format string to make sure you don't read any more than that.

Comment: Ok. Let me show you what I have now. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's `for(x = ARRAY; x < LUNCHES; ++x)` - note the `<` instead of `<=`, otherwise you'll overflow the array (the index is zero-based, it runs from `0` to `LUNCHES-1`).

As for the allocation:

- you need to create buffer for every entry in the `lunch[]` array, hence in the for loop you need something like `lunch[x].name = malloc(SIZE)`, where `SIZE` is a reasonable value - for the purpose of meal name ~80 characters would seem more than enough;
- next you **must** to check, that the pointer assigned to `lunch[x].name` is not `NULL`, which would signal out of memory condition - otherwise you might happen to cause a segmentation fault by dereferencing it;
- then you can use the pointer (to the newly allocated buffer) as the argument to `scanf()`, but remember to specify the maximum width (i.e. `SIZE-1`), so that you don't overrun into unallocated memory.

Remember to use `free()` on the pointers to allocated memory when you don't need the data any more or at the end of the program - while in your simple example it's technically not necessary, it could easily start a very bad habit.

Comment: I know about the free. I just didn't get to that point yet. Thanks

Comment: Isn't it possible to have the program figure out how much memory to use depending on the meal name string size?

Comment: Sure, if you know how many items you are going to use. But then the question is, why not to put the array into the struct directly, as in `struct Food { char name[NAMELEN]; ... }`